# Slanted square with grid

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw grid on the slanted square `ABCD`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=round,font=\small]
\draw[lightgray] (0,0) grid (7,7);
\coordinate[label=below:$A$] (A) at (4,0);
\coordinate[label=right:$B$] (B) at (7,4);
\coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C) at (3,7);
\coordinate[label=left:$D$] (D) at (0,3);
\draw[thick] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I mean like this.

[image]

Comment: add two grids one with `rotate=50` option or whatever the angle is

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rotated grid inside the square can be drawn by coordinates given by partway modifiers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=round,font=\small]
\coordinate[label=below:$A$] (A) at (4,0);
\coordinate[label=right:$B$] (B) at (7,4);
\coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C) at (3,7);
\coordinate[label=left:$D$] (D) at (0,3);

\draw[lightgray]
  (0, 0) grid (7, 7)
  \foreach \i in {1, ..., 4} {
    ($(A)!\i/5!(B)$) -- ($(D)!\i/5!(C)$)
    ($(B)!\i/5!(C)$) -- ($(A)!\i/5!(D)$)
  }
;

\draw[thick] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Just on this answer I found the right trick, thanks!

Comment: The loop over j is redundant here.

Comment: @AndrewD.King Thanks, the redundant loop is now removed.

Answer (score 3):

A [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) alternative (just for comparison).  Compile with `lualatex`.

[image: Slanted squares and grids]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

   path box[];
   box0 = unitsquare shifted -(1/2,1/2);
   box1 = box0 scaled 7cm;
   box2 = box0 scaled 5cm rotated angle (3,4);

   vardef draw_grid(expr Q,N) = 
       for t=1 upto N-1:
           draw point t/N   of Q -- point 3-t/N of Q;
           draw point 1+t/N of Q -- point 4-t/N of Q;
       endfor
   enddef;

   drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 white);
   draw_grid(box1,7);
   draw_grid(box2,5);

   drawoptions();
   draw box1;
   draw box2;

   label.bot("$A$", point 0 of box2);
   label.rt ("$B$", point 1 of box2);
   label.top("$C$", point 2 of box2);
   label.lft("$D$", point 3 of box2);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```